# Failing to install yum package - Package does not match intended download

Tags: rpm, yum

I have this yum repo hosted on my some machine in my network, and I've been using it to install an RPM on my own machine. I updated the RPM, and moved it over to the machine hosting the yum repo, but now when I try `yum install package`, I get:

```
package-1.0-1.el7.x86_64 FAILED                                          
http://10.10.202.82/centos/7/extras/x86_64/package-1.0-1.el7.x86_64.rpm: [Errno -1] Package does not match intended download. Suggestion: run yum --enablerepo=10.10.202.82_centos_7_extras_x86_64 clean metadata
Trying other mirror.


Error downloading packages:
  package-1.0-1.el7.x86_64: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
```

I tried `yum clean metadata` and `yum clean all`, along with the suggested command, with no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try re-creating the repo on the machine hosting the repo to update repomd.

Then try the following on your machine and try installing again:

```
rm -r /var/cache/yum
yum clean all
```

Comment: I had to recreate the repodata. If anyone's curious, I did that with `createrepo --update --workers=4 <RPM_location>`